# Jquery Onclick text to text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Onclick I want to change the text to input field. If I change the value in the input field  and click anywhere, back to text. I found this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/767y4/8/

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).find('input').length){
                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
            }
            else {
                var t = $(this).text();
                $(this).text('').append($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
            }
        });
});
```

I used this fiddle. But the input value not changed to text. Please see my updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ach3/

How can to achieve this?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5Ach3/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/5Ach3/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ach3/7/)**

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {

         var t = $(this).text();
         $(this).text('').append($('<input />',{'value' : t}));
         $('input').focus();


});

$('#tbl').on('blur','input',function() {
    $(this).parent().text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Goodluck, revert back in case of any problem!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to transform text to input on click you can use `contenteditable="true"` html property.
You don't need any JS with this way.

```
<p contenteditable="true">my text</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ec5C/